# How to update an Oracle view from Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework-5

My EF schema is containing views, and it is bound with an Oracle database. 
Also, I do not have any control over the schema of my Oracle database, I am allowed to perform only DML operations over the views/ tables.
I can see the data getting loaded in my MVC view. There is another view, which loads individual record, and there user can change any field, and can hit the Save to update the underlying view. I know this is not as straightforward as updating tables, and so it is giving an error of operation state. Could anyone please guide me a proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to change the XML of EDMX file, and should change the type of the correponding view to table, in the Conceptual model's section.